# Shopping cart's item will not update quantity

Tags: php, html, shopping-cart

I am making a dummy online store for a university project. Ive run into a problem I can't get my head around. Items can be added/removed from the cart but the quantity will not be updated if someone tries to add an item that already exists in the cart.

The HTML shown is the code that displays the item on the homepage.php that can be added to the cart.

The PHP shown is code that works with the 'add' action - Adding new item to cart, or if it is already current, it should add the quantity selected to the quantity already in the cart. The latter function will not work.

### HTML

```
<div class="laptops"><br />
                <img src="<?php echo "img/" . $row["img"] ?>"><br />
                <div class="laptopText">
                    <h3><?php echo $row["brand"] . $row["model"] ?></h3><br />
                    <p><?php echo $row["cpu_type"] . ", " . $row["cpu_model"] . ", " . $row["OS"] . ", " . $row["RAM"] . ", " . $row["RAM_type"] . ", " . $row["storage"] . ", " . $row["display"] . ", " . $row["gpu"]?></p><br />
                    <p class="price"><?php echo "£" . $row["price"] ?></p><br />
                    <div class="itemFormDiv">
                        <form method="post" action="homepage.php?action=add&id=<?php echo $row["ID"] ?>">
                            <input class="quantity" name="quantity" type="number" min="1" max="9" value="1">
                            <input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" value="<?php echo $row["brand"] . $row["model"] ?>">
                            <input type="hidden" name="hidden_desc" value="<?php echo $row["cpu_type"] . ", " . $row["cpu_model"] . ", " . $row["OS"] . ", " . $row["RAM"] . ", " . $row["RAM_type"] . ", " . $row["storage"] . ", " . $row["display"] . ", " . $row["gpu"]?>">
                            <input type="hidden" name="hidden_price" value="<?php echo $row["price"] ?>">
                            <input class="addTooBasket" name="addTooBasket" type="submit" value="Add to Basket">
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

(When I add the PHP to stackoverflow it keeps preventing me from submitting the question so here it is on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/t53BbC3u) )
Can anyone work out how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `$counter = 0;` before foreach, increment it in the end of each step and try something like `$_SESSION["shopping_basket"][$counter]['item_quantity'] += intval($_POST["quantity"]);`

Comment: I am very confused. Ive implemented your code and now it seems to make a new item in basket but with no traits apart from quantity. It doesn't actually change that perticular items quantity at all..

Comment: Additional adding of quantity then updates the new item's (with no traits) quantity.

Comment: try without counter `$_SESSION["shopping_basket"][$key]['item_quantity'] += intval($_POST["quantity"]);`